# How to access anonymous object's property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, anonymous-types

I have a WinForms combobox to which I bind a list of anonymous objects (printer descriptions and locations).

The **goal** here is a to select a default printer (which matches printer location).

But within a `foreach` loop below, I am having trouble accessing the anonymous object's properties.

[image]

I know of a work-around (I tried a private nested DTO with Location & Description property)
 but **is there a way to access anonymous object's properties without creating a concrete class**?

Maybe I was just *too* lazy here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are, but they're far more hackish.  Go with the concrete class.

To name a few:

1. Reflection
2. Typing by example

But to be sure, both of the above items will require more coding than it will take to create a simple POCO.

Comment: Thanks, David; Hearing that *Reflection* made me cringe... and ended up implementing it with a simple `POCO` ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to share an object between functions then you need to use a concrete class.  Anonymous types are only useful for sharing data within a function or to a binding interface